# Need to find the value of 3 unknown variables

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following:

```
x = p/y - d/y

y = p + d + n
```

I know x and I know y.

I'm just really stuck at this point and don't know how to solve this to find p and d.

Example numbers

```
x=0.33

y=10

0.33 = p/10 - d/10
```

Since i know that p+d cannot be above 10, I know that p=6 and d=3. I can't think of a way to programatically solve this though.

Comment: To find 3 unknown variables you need 3 distinct equations.

Comment: $p=(xy+y+n)/2$, and $d=p-xy$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: rewrite the system in the form $$xy=p-d$$ and $$y-n=p+d$$ and now you can add both equations

Comment: The logic is to add the two equations, as the answer says.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!